# How to call a function within a class in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, methods

When running this code, I am attempting to get the same output in flipper.swim() that I get from Salmon.swim().  The Salmon.swim() properly outputs the string from that method, but when I call flipper.swim(), I get the following error: TypeError: swim() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

```
class Fish (object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def swim():
        print("The fish swam.")


class Salmon(Fish):
    pass

flipper = Fish("FLIPPER")

Salmon.swim()
Fish.swim()
print(flipper.name)
flipper.swim()
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the response.  I don't think I'm getting this. I entered "x" into the swim(method) and I am now getting a different error:

class Fish (object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def swim(x):
        print("The fish swam.")


class Salmon(Fish):
    pass

flipper = Fish("FLIPPER")

Salmon.swim()
Fish.swim()
print(flipper.name)
flipper.swim()

>>>TypeError: swim() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
class Fish (object):

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def swim(self):
    print(self.name + " swam.")

class Salmon(Fish):
    pass

flipper = Fish("FLIPPER")
salmon = Salmon("FOO")

Salmon.swim(flipper)
Fish.swim(flipper)
print(flipper.name)
Fish.swim(flipper)
Fish.swim(salmon)
```

The above will output:

```
FLIPPER swam.
FLIPPER swam.
FLIPPER
FLIPPER swam.
FOO swam.
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks @hfontanez!  It appears that I was missing the 'self' argument in my "swim()" method.  Got it!

Answer (score 0):

you get the error because python automatically pass the instance of your class (flipper in your sample code) as the first argument to your method `swim`, that by convention we call *self*, to turn off this behavior you need to specify that said method doesn't require/use your instance of this class, and that is done with the [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator

```
class Fish (object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def swim():
        print("The fish swam.")
```

Comment: Got it!  This makes sense too!